# Terminal prompt disappeared?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal

I was fooling around in “Terminal” (Mac OS 10.6) and typed in `sudo ping -f` but didn’t put in a URL and didn’t hit <kbd>return</kbd>, instead closing the application.

When I opened it again the prompt that appears right before any text you type was gone. I can type just fine, but when I hit the <kbd>return</kbd> key, the cursor just moves to the next line without completing the command. How do I fix this? I’ve tried quitting & re-opening “Terminal,” as well as sending a reset (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and then a hard reset (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

Comment: It looks like you created a second account rather than logging into the original one, which prevents you from editing your own question.  Please see this link about merging your accounts: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did something that might have damaged or appended unwanted items to `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. This [site explains the differences](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` and [this site explains how to customize](http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/) your “Terminal” prompt. Both should be helpful in giving basic clues as to what might have happened.

In general, most users will never have a need for a `.bashrc` unless you have explicitly installed software that uses that. Most users will—however—have at least one or two minor adjustments to `.bash_profile` to adjust things like `$PATH` and such.

But you say this:

> I can type just fine, but when I hit the <kbd>return</kbd> key, the cursor just
>   moves to the next line without completing the command.

That is a bit disconcerting. Because all of the options to inspect, repair or replace `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` would require you to be able to actively run commands in the “Terminal” to access those files.

So my best suggestion to you would be to create a new user on your Mac OS X machine who has administrator/`sudo` rights, login as that user, but then use your elevated rights as an administrator to go to the `/Users/[your username]` directory and inspect, repair or replace the contents of the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files.

The simplest non-destructive thing you can do is to login as that new administrator user and then run these commands to copy/neuter the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files by giving them new filenames like this:

```
sudo mv /Users/[your username]/.bashrc /Users/[your username]/.bashrc_OLD

sudo mv /Users/[your username]/.bash_profile /Users/[your username]/.bash_profile_OLD
```

Of course you need to change `[your username]` to match the actual username of the user with the “Terminal” issues in question, but after you do that, login as the older user with the original “Terminal” issues and see if that cleans things up. Fairly confident it will.

But on the off-chance this does not resolve the issue, you should edit your question to perhaps provide more details as to which exact `sudo` command you attempted to run when you closed the “Terminal” window. You say you didn’t hit <kbd>return</kbd>, but something clearly happened at that moment. So knowing what the exact command was can provide clues as to how to unravel this issue you are facing.

Comment: Another way of doing the same thing, if the machine is running a service like FTP or SFTP, is to connect to the machine (with `ftp` or whatever) and rename the file(s) that way.